# Error when pass date from PHP to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my PHP code to send a date to MYSQL, but when i open the management tool of my database i get this values: `0000-00-00 00:00:00` Mysql type is set to "datetime".

```
...    
$dataprova = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   
$query = "INSERT INTO oxybet(data) VALUES ('&dataprova')";
if (mysql_query($query)) { 
   echo "ok";
   echo($dataprova); 
} else { 
   echo "error"; 
} 
...
```

While in my page i correctly obtain: `2014-04-20 15:22:15`, db show `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

What is the error?

Comment: Is `&dataprova` a typo here or in your code as well?

Comment: `&dataprova` !== `$dataprova`

Comment: There is no error. If you want to see the error, enable MYSQL strict mode. You're right now casting some stringy '&dataprova' to a date which is correctly 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as date. So no error. - Lesson one for Mysql debugging: Check what the actual query was. Don't fly blind.

Comment: You can prevent such errors to some degree by using parametrized queries or just good old `sprintf()` even.

Comment: Mark baker does the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO oxybet(data) VALUES ('&dataprova')";
```

Change to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO oxybet(data) VALUES ('$dataprova')";
```